# Can I use dynamic relationships (or VIEWS) in SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a way, so that a relationship *only uses some rows of a table*, instead of the whole table.

> I was thinking about using a **view** instead of the original table as base for the relationship. Where the *view* contains only a filtered set of rows from the original table.

### Example

I want to collect statistical information for songs (rating, play-count, last time played) from a couple of players over different devices and from different users. I use *Python* and [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

I came up with the following table layout (you can take a look at the [code for the objects](https://gist.github.com/brutus/7483771) and the [SQL for the tables](https://gist.github.com/brutus/7335121)):

[image: ERP]

### The problem

For each `Song` object I can easily get *all the associated* `Stats` objects. But most of the time I only want *some of them*. I only want those `Stats` for a `Song` that relate to one or more `Commit`, eg. only the data from all commits by a given user, or one certain commit.

**So I need some way to filter the stats data on the song object.**

I'm not quiet sure how to archive this.

Should I use some custom query? But where do I place it and how? Also: while this might give me the data I want (`select path, rating... over the three joined tables` or [something along those lines](https://gist.github.com/brutus/7486362)), I won't get objects back.

I was thinking about using a **view** on the `stats` table, containing only the lines matching the given `commits`. The view has to be created dynamically trough, so different commits can be filtered. And than using this view as the base for a relationship from `songs` to `stats`. But I have no idea how to do it.

So: Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Or how to solve this another way?

Comment: Right now I use direct SQL queries like [this](https://gist.github.com/brutus/7486362). It gives me the data, but I much rather like to have the `Song` objects and only the filtered `Stats` mapped to it, so I can process them further on the `Song` object.

Comment: I have an idea on how this could be accomplished, but I need a few more details. Would this view be temporary or materialized? Are you using Postgresql? So what you'd like is in python to create a view on the first time Stats is queried with a commit_id. All subsequent queries for that query will use that view, instead of the original table?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import object_session
# defined inside of your Song class
def stats_by_commit(self,commit):
    #this could also be implemented as a join
    return object_session(self).query(Stat)\
           .filter(Stat.song_id == self.song_id,Stat.commit_id == Commit.commit_id)
```

Usage:

```
commit = db_session.query(Commit).filter_by(id=1)
for song in db_session.query(Song).filter_by(path='some_song_path'):
    for stat in song.stats_by_commit(self,commit):
        print stat.rating
```

Comment: Cool, I never heard of `object_session` before. I can't test your code right now, but it looks good. Although this is more like the workaround I'm using now, than the thing I'm looking for. I tried to make the question more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand why you want to use a view versus a query. Some motivation maybe be helpful...